# Finding ratio of perimeter with surrounding neighbors in R

Tags: r, gis, spatial, r-sf

I have a shape file at [Sample Data](https://github.com/ahadzaman1002/example_data.git)

I read the data in R as sf object named "SD" and have columns "GEOID" and "geometry" along with other columns.
I created a new column in the data named "POP"

```
SD$POP <- sample(2000:8000, 35)
```

First, I want to measure the area and perimeter for each "GEOID".

Second, I need to find how ratio of each GEOID's perimeter  shared with it's surrounding GEOIDs.
For example: say GEOID 09 is surrounded by GEOID 06, 08, 10, 13. I want to find what percent of GEOID 09's perimeter is shared with 06, 08, 10, and 13 individually.
Then Create new columns  "POP_PERCENT" and "ADJ_POP" which will be

```
ADJ-POP = SUM OF POP for GEOID 06, 08, 10, and 13' .

POP_PERCENT =  Percent share with 06 + Percent share with 08 + Percent share with 10 +
Percent share with 13
```

My apologies for verbose question. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think generally what you need is `st_intersection` plus some data manipulation. The dataset does not have a `GEOID` column, and I'm not completely clear what the expected output for `POP_PERCENT` is (adjacent population weighted by percent perimeter overlap?). So this isn't a totally complete answer.

Here is a start using `sf` and some other `tidyverse` functions. This calculates the area, perimeter, and intersections of each polygon. I created a `GEOID` column from the `rownames`. Hopefully that is enough to get you going in the right direction.

First calculate area and perimeter of each

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

SD_ap <- SD %>%
  st_transform(5070) %>% #convert from lat/long to projected coord system
  mutate(area = st_area(.),
         length_perim = lwgeom::st_perimeter(.))

#-----
  GEOID  POP                       geometry              area         perim
1     1 6582 MULTIPOLYGON (((860088.4 12...   357945281 [m^2]  139932.2 [m]
2     2 3199 MULTIPOLYGON (((843395.6 11...   137754181 [m^2]  100879.4 [m]
```

Then calculate the overlapping perimeters. Convert the polygons to lines, then run `st_intersection`. Instead of the 35 polygons, this returns 141 line segments, distinguished by original overlapping polygons (`origins`)

```
SD_overlap <- SD_ap %>%
  st_cast('MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_intersection() %>%
  mutate(length_intersection = st_length(.)) %>%
  filter(length_intersection > units::as_units(0,'m'))

#----
     GEOID  POP              area  length_perim n.overlaps origins length_intersection
1        1 6559   357945281 [m^2]  139932.2 [m]          2    1, 2        6761.611 [m]
2        2 4781   137754181 [m^2]  100879.4 [m]          2    2, 3       24201.037 [m]
2.2      2 4781   137754181 [m^2]  100879.4 [m]          2    2, 4       31628.198 [m]
3        3 3424   295676500 [m^2]  212930.4 [m]          2    3, 4       22967.725 [m]
```

Plot the first 4 `GEOID`s to check this is working out as expected

```
ggplot(data = filter(SD, GEOID %in% 1:4),
       aes(fill = as.factor(GEOID),
           label = GEOID)) +
  geom_sf(alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf(data = filter(SD_overlap, map_lgl(origins, ~all(.x %in% 1:4))), 
          aes(color = map_chr(origins, ~paste(.x, collapse = ','))),
          fill = NA,
          lwd = 2,
          show.legend = 'line') +
  geom_sf_label(fill = "white",  # override the fill from aes()
                fun.geometry = sf::st_centroid) +
  guides(fill = 'none')+
  labs(color='Overlap')
```

[image]

---

To answer the question of what populations are adjacent, you can try something like this.

```
sum_adj_pops <- function(GEOID_i){
  
  ID_adj <- SD_overlap %>%
    st_drop_geometry() %>%
    filter(map_lgl(origins, ~GEOID_i %in% .x)) %>%
    unnest_longer(origins) %>%
    filter(origins != GEOID_i) %>%
    pull(origins)
  
  SD %>%
    st_drop_geometry() %>%
    filter(GEOID %in% ID_adj) %>%
    summarize(POP_adj = sum(POP)) %>%
    pull(POP_adj)
}

SD %>%
  mutate(POP_adj = map_dbl(GEOID, sum_adj_pops))

#----
   GEOID  POP                       geometry POP_adj
1      1 6559 MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.64623 3...   24024
2      2 4781 MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.861 33....   27132
3      3 3424 MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.97402 3...   21907
4      4 4230 MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.74407 3...   22259
5      5 7054 MULTIPOLYGON (((-87.78275 3...   22021
```

---

Data

```
url_shp <- 'https://github.com/ahadzaman1002/example_data/raw/main/fe_2007_01_sldu00.zip'

tmp_zip <- tempfile(fileext = '.zip')
tmp_dir <- tempdir()
download.file(url = url_shp, tmp_zip)
unzip(tmp_zip, exdir = tmp_dir)

path_shp <- list.files(tmp_dir, '.shp$', full.names = TRUE)

set.seed(415) #for reproducibility with sample()

SD <- st_read(path_shp) %>%
  mutate(POP = sample(2000:8000, 35)) %>%
  rowid_to_column('GEOID')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer @nniloc. If I use st_transform(4326) then lwgeom::st_perimeter(.) function does not work. How do I determine which epsg is to use time to time. 
One more thing - if I convert the polygons to "MULTILINESTRING", then I can get a length using st_length. Is this is similar to perimeter? Furthermore, If don't convert the polygons to

Comment: You have to choose a projected coordinate system (with units like feet or meters) rather than a geographic coordinate system (where units are degrees). If you look up [4326](https://epsg.io/4326) you can see the units are degrees, while for [5070](https://epsg.io/5070) the units are meters

Comment: One more thing - if I convert the polygons to "MULTILINESTRING", then I can get a length using st_length(). Is this is similar to perimeter? Furthermore, If don't convert the polygons to "MULTILINESTRING", then st_intersection( ) gives 0 output. Why does this happens. I have little to no knowledge in GIS data. If you could refer me some learning material I would appreciate. THANK YOU.

Comment: Converting from polygon to lines returns the perimeter line. This allows for easier calculation of the length of overlap between the perimeters. Otherwise the intersection of polygons would be an area. I believe `st_length` on the line should be the same as `st_perimeter` (before you run `st_intersection`).

Comment: One of the resources I use consistently. Check out the book. r-spatial.org